# Push and join methods dont work correctly

Tags: reactjs

i'm practicing in react and  trying to add classNames in array using push method after event (onClick) but it doesnt work although console returns new array with correct meanings but the element  which must get this classNames hasn't it

```
function ProductSelection(){
let clrListClasses = ['clr_list' ]
function ShowColor(){
        if(clrListClasses.includes('show') == false){
            clrListClasses.push('show')
            console.log(clrListClasses)
        }
    }
return(
<span className="arrow" onClick={() => ShowColor()}  > &gt; </span>
<ul className={clrListClasses.join(' ')}>
<li>some text </li><li>some text </li><li>some text </li></ul>
)
}
```

Comment: There is a problem with the code formatting. Select your code and hit CTRL + K.
Moreover could you show the code where you give the className to a component ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because each time the component function is called by React the `clrListClasses` variable is replaced with a new one. To persist state accross renders you have to use `useState`.

The following will work:

```
// Use useState hook
const [clrListClasses, setClrListClasses] = useState(['clr_list' ]);
function ShowColor(){
    if(clrListClasses.includes('show') == false) {
        // Set the state
        setClrListClasses(existing => existing.concat("show"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah thanks it works, but i replace concat to push and now after second click when i want to remove this className returns error "clrListClasses.includes is not a function"